# How to mask URL for a C# MVC site with multiple tenant sub-domains

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a .NET MVC site with multiple tenants all with their own sub-domains. And I'm trying to mask the controller location for a certain subset of those tenants as they're segmented to an area of the site.

For example I want subdomain.domain.com to point to /Controller/View without the extra stuff on the end of the domain.

More specifically,

http://subdomain.domain.com/Controller/View

Becomes:

http://subdomain.domain.com

What's the best way to accomplish this? In the Web.config?

Comment: are you trying remove "Controller/View" part from site url ?

Comment: @hasan right exactly, there is a specific part of the site I need the subdomain to point to, hiding the Controller/View from the user

Comment: my answer can make sense for your need, you can create custom MapRoute to achieve your goal

Comment: did my answer work?

Comment: @hasan, Sorry for late reply. I don't know if it worked or not. I got pulled off this project and haven't picked it back up. If I ever get back to it I'll reply. Haven't forgotten!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this in global.asax to remove controller and view part from url.

```
routes.MapRoute("SpecificRoute", "/{id}", new {controller = "YourController", action = "YourAction", id = UrlParameter.Optional});

// default route
routes.MapRoute("Default", "{controller}/{action}/{id}", new {controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional} );
```

Also you can use `Route()` over your action

```
[Route("")]
public ActionResult YourAction()
{
...
}
```

Url will be like http://example.com/